# C# How to call a subfunc once when func is called multiple times

Tags: c#, func

Start with some example:

```
public abstract class T
{

void subfunc() { /*code*/ }

void func()
   subfunc();
   //code
}
```

When I call in main method T.func() multiply times, I need that subfunc() will be called only first time, when func() is called first time. I don't really want to call it in mainMethod because it doesn't refer there logically.

Comment: Keep a flag to check if the subfunc() is already called once or not. For instance , if(isFirstTime){ subfunc(); isFirstTime = false;}

Comment: Or maybe [`Lazy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you need to get some sort of value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a parameter in your func which states whether subFunc needs to be called or not

```
callSubFunc = true;
func(callSubFunc);
callSubFunc = false;
//further calls of func(callSubFunc) will pass false everytime
```

and modify func as follows:-

```
void func(bool shouldCallSubFunc)
{
    if(shouldCallSubFunc)
        subFunc()
}
```

hope this helps